# Problemas com o módulo request npm

Tags: javascript, http, http-request

Estou com algumas dificuldades em realizar requisições HTTP.

O código:

```js
import Request from 'Request';

function xxx (tomboCodBarra){
    const options = {
        url: `http://servicos.jbrj.gov.br/v2/herbarium/${tomboCodBarra}`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
            'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
            Connection: 'keep-alive',
            Host: 'servicos.jbrj.gov.br',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        },
    };
    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
        const json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json);
    });
}
```

Então, um exemplo de `tomboCodBarra` é `RB01364063`. A saída desse código deveria ser um JSON, como segue abaixo:

```js
{
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "occurrenceid": 4799256,
      "rightsholder": "RB",
      "bibliographiccitation": "Herbário Virtual REFLORA Disponível em: http://herbariovirtualreflora.jbrj.gov.br/reflora/herbarioVirtual/ConsultaPublicoHVUC/ConsultaPublicoHVUC.do?idTestemunho=4799256",
      "modified": null,
      "institutioncode": "RB",
      "collectioncode": "RB",
      "catalognumber": "RB01364063",
      "occurrenceremarks": "",
      "recordedby": "P.E. Ellert- Pereira;G. Heiden,L.H. Dal Molin,M.P. Estabão",
      "recordnumber": "86",
      "othercatalognumbers": "",
      "eventdate": "10/8/2015",
      "year": 2015,
      "month": 8,
      "day": 10,
      "verbatimeventdate": "10/08/2015",
      "fieldnotes": "Planta até 3 metros de altura. Frutos imaturos verdes; quase maduros roxo-esverdeados a quase completamente roxos",
      "country": "Brasil",
      "countrycode": "BR",
      "stateprovince": "Goiás",
      "municipality": "Jataí",
      "locality": "Saída em direção a Rio Verde. Rancho Alto das Rosas",
      "minimumelevationinmeters": null,
      "maximumelevationinmeters": null,
      "verbatimlatitude": null,
      "verbatimlongitude": null,
      "decimallatitude": "-17.9161111111111",
      "decimallongitude": "-51.6952777777778",
      "identifiedby": "P.E. Ellert- Pereira",
      "identificationverificationstatus": null,
      "dateidentified": "10/8/2015",
      "identificationremarks": "",
      "identificationqualifier": null,
      "typestatus": null,
      "scientificname": "Arecaceae Butia purpurascens Glassman",
      "family": "Arecaceae",
      "genus": "Butia",
      "specificepithet": "purpurascens",
      "infraspecificepithet": null,
      "taxonrank": "ESPECIE",
      "scientificnameauthorship": "Glassman",
      "type": null,
      "rights": "Creative Commons",
      "associatedmedia": "http://imagens1.jbrj.gov.br/fsi/server?type=image&source=rb/1/36/40/63/01364063-3.jpg|http://imagens1.jbrj.gov.br/fsi/server?type=image&source=rb/1/36/40/63/01364063-2.jpg|http://imagens1.jbrj.gov.br/fsi/server?type=image&source=rb/1/36/40/63/01364063-1.jpg|http://imagens1.jbrj.gov.br/fsi/server?type=image&source=rb/1/36/40/63/01364063-4.jpg|http://imagens1.jbrj.gov.br/fsi/server?type=image&source=rb/1/36/40/63/01364063.jpg",
      "eventremarks": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Porém tem vezes que ele não retorna o JSON acima, e sim o abaixo:

```js
{ erro: '500',
  message: 'Oops, something\'s gone wrong in server!' }
```

Então algumas ideias que eu tentei fazer para que esse JSON não seja o retornado foi:

- Utilizar outros módulos, como `got, axios, node-wget, superagent`, porém o mesmo erro acontece;
- Eu tentei combinar esses módulos, caso um desse retornassem o JSON inesperado eu iria para os outros módulos, porém não funcionou;
- Utilizei também outros módulos, como `sync-request, sync-exec` (o `sync-exec` eu utilizei para realizar o `curl` ou `wget` para conseguir realizar a requisição), porém dava um erro de *time out*;
- Utilizei também outros módulos, como `http, httpclient, http-client`(algo assim, não lembro os nomes deles), porém não retornavam erro, nem o JSON com erro 500 e nem o JSON correto;
- Utilizei o módulo `python-shell`, na qual eu fiz um programa em Python que somente fazia a requisição e dava um `print` na resposta, porém o JSON com erro 500 era retornado e também era retornado um erro de *time out*;
- Em um lugar eu vi que adicionar parâmetros de requisição talvez resolveria esse problema, por isso eu fiz uma requisição pelo Firefox e peguei os parâmetros que foram utilizados, porém não resolveu.
- Eu tentei colocar em um *loop infinito* em que ele somente sairia desse laço se retornasse o JSON esperado, porém acabou retornando erros relacionado com *time out*;
- Eu tentei rodar no Windows 7 64 bits (atualmente estou rodando no Linux Mint 19 Tara 64 bits), porém nada.
- **E O MAIS INTERESSANTE** é que eu fiz dois programas em Java e Python (a parte desse meu código em JavaScript), que fazia a requisição de 20 mil (que é o quanto eu necessito) códigos de barras, porém eles não retornavam esse JSON, com código de erro 500;

Então a minha versão do node é v10.15.0. Alguém tem ideia de algum módulo que eu possa utilizar ou alguma ideia de como fazer essa requisição?

Comment: **xandão**, seja bem vindo ao **Stack Overflow em português**, editei sua pergunta removendo ruídos ( saudação, etc ) e também as tags que irrelevantes. Leia o [tour] para saber como o site funciona e caso necessite de ajuda sobre como fazer utilização das ferramentes do mesmo, acesse a [help].

Comment: Beleza, obrigado!